# C find string in text diagonally

Tags: c, algorithm

Can anyone help me to organize such function ( as a homework I manage with crossword program ):

1) I have array of strings ( kind of text file ), where

`row[0] = "str1"`
`row[1] = "str2"` and etc.

2) The length of each string is same

3) Inputted word from stdin like `abcd`

I need to find word `abcd` in text located **diagonally** ( from left to right doesn't really matter just need kind of algorithm ) and replace found word with zeros.
First letter can be found with `strchr` but how correctly go forward and replace text with zeros? Can anyone give me any clue?

SOLUTION:

Tnx for minusing by the way. I've found another solution where each diagonal line is generated into 1 simple line, then I apply `strstr` to it to find position of match. Knowing position of match and length of matched string enables to detect precisely position of matched cells in array of lines.

I used such code ( maybe smn will find it useful ):

```
  /* generating left-right diagonal string str */
  for( col = cols - len; col >= 0; col --, i = 0 ){
  /* where len is the length of searching string */

  while( ( col+i ) < cols && i < rows ){
    *(str + i) = res[i][col+i];
    i ++;
  }

  *(str + i) = '\0';

  //some match seq.
  }
```

I did for left right diagonal from left top cell ( start of first string ) to last top cell ( end of first string ). Then same procedure for left column, so resulted algorithm will cover all strings.

Comment: People don't generally like being asked to do your homework for you.

Comment: Is this a complete crossword (ie: no disallowed cells within a square/rectangular grid)? I did something similar where I wrote a simply set of `is4Neighbour/is4DiagNeighbor/is8Neighbour` functions to determine if a cell has neighbours. I then recursively create a list of all diagonals, convert them to 1-D arrays, then call the strstr() function on them.

Comment: It's a small part of homework, I don't know how to do it quickly as crossword can be big, and I'm asking not to do it for me, but for a clue how to do it correctly. Read carefully

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to have a 2-dimentonal array of characters such as

```
char grid[i][j]
```

and if your first letter is at `grid[i][j]` than a next point in the diagonal is at

```
grid[i+1][j+1]
```

And so on for every combination of `+1` and `-1`

Answer (score 1):

Find first letter, lets say at row[5] the letter with index 7 (so `row[5][7]`).
Then check if `row[6][8]` is the second letter; or `row[4][6]`, or `row[4][8]` or `row[6][6]`. Proceed with third letter, probably recursevily.